# RxJS execution order after subject emission

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to understand the code execution order following a 'next' call on a Subject.

Background: I have 3 classes (call them HaveSubject, HaveSubscription1, HaveSubscription2). HaveSubject needs to tell HS1 and HS2 to do something through a Subject that HS1 and HS2 are subscribed to. Their tasks must be completed before HaveSubject goes on to execute method somethingVeryImportant.

Pseudocode:

```
class HaveSubject {
    // Angular service
    public mySubject$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    public codeImExecuting() {
        this.mySubject$.next('input for tasks')
        this.somethingVeryImportant();
    }

    private somethingVeryImportant() {
        // stuff
    }
}

class HaveSubscription1 {
    // Angular service
    constructor(private hs: HaveSubject) {
        this.hs.mySubject$.subscribe(inputStr => {
            // did I do this before somethingVeryImportant is called?
        });
    }
}

class HaveSubscription2 {
    // Angular service
    constructor(private hs: HaveSubject) {
        this.hs.mySubject$.subscribe(inputStr => {
            // did I do this before somethingVeryImportant is called?
        });
    }
}
```

My question is: what is the best way to ensure that HS1 and HS2 have executed the code attached to their subscriptions before going on to execute method somethingVeryImportant? If the order of operations is: HaveSubject calls 'next' on subject -> HS1 and HS2 do their tasks -> HaveSubject goes on to its next line of code, which is somethingVeryImportant, then I have no issues. I'm just not sure that subscriptions are executed immediately after they receive the 'next' item in the subscription.

NOTE: There are a few things I can't do that I would normally, such as have HaveSubject inject into the other two, because the other two are created dynamically (i.e. I may have none, one, or both of HaveSubscriptionX, not clear how many will be created, and these are Angular services that are provided by a component, not in the root...).

Thoughts?

Comment: I would probably have the somethingImportant take a function to execute mySubject.next as a parameter and then somethingImportant fires the function when it is done. Or have something improtant return an observable that completes when somethingImportant is done, subscribing to that observable can give you a chance to fire the .next()

Comment: Bob - so it sounds like you're not sure if subscriptions will execute right after the next call (i.e. before the line of code that comes right after the next call)?

Comment: Correct, I think the nature of the asynchronous paradigm is that you don't know/can't be sure how execution order will happen. I very well could be wrong, it just seems wrong to assume you can squeeze in some operations before the subscriptions get fired.

Comment: Would you architect this differently? It sounds like something is being done in a suspect way

Comment: @bryan60 I'm curious if you have any thoughts on how this might otherwise be accomplished. The key issue is that we typically need to communicate between components via services, but that if components are being created dynamically (and providing their own services), how to set up communication between these services isn't super clear to me. I'm also relatively new to the Angular environment, so any advice / best practices would be helpful.

Comment: I suppose I could create one super-service that contains all this functionality, but that seems like kind of a pain...

Comment: if I had a clearer idea of what the actual use case is here (ie why `somethingVeryImportant` needs to be run AFTER whatever the consumers of `mySubject$` are doing or what you're generally trying to accomplish) I could probably recommend something.

Comment: Or just generally why the chain of events is `codeImExecuting` -> `mySubject$` consumers -> `somethingVeryImportant`

Comment: @bryan60 Essentially, we want HaveSubject to use data in HS# in order to produce an output for the user. Again, I would prefer to inject HS# into HaveSubject, but the dynamic nature of their creation makes that unclear to me (perhaps there's a way and I'm just not experienced enough to have seen it...).

Comment: i mean, it seems like you are already injecting HaveSubject into HS# so I'm confused on the issue there?

Comment: Sorry -- mistyped -- I meant injecting HS# into HaveSubject -- updated in edit, but you read before that.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest call events on finishing side work in `HaveSubscription#` (not ideal a lot duplicated run check second option)

```js
class HaveSubject {
    // Angular service
    public mySubject$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
    public mySubjectDone$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    public constructor() {
        this.mySubjectDone$.subscribe(this.somethingVeryImportant.bind(this));
    }

    public codeImExecuting() {
        this.mySubject$.next('input for tasks')
    }

    private somethingVeryImportant() {
        // stuff
    }
}

class HaveSubscription1 {
    // Angular service
    constructor(private hs: HaveSubject) {
        this.hs.mySubject$.subscribe(inputStr => {
            // did I do this before somethingVeryImportant is called?
            hs.mySubjectDone$.next()
        });
    }
}

class HaveSubscription2 {
    // Angular service
    constructor(private hs: HaveSubject) {
        this.hs.mySubject$.subscribe(inputStr => {
            // did I do this before somethingVeryImportant is called?
            hs.mySubjectDone$.next()
        });
    }
}
```

or if you dont want to require any actions from `HaveSubscription#` trigger delayed action

```js
class HaveSubject {
    // Angular service
    public mySubject$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();

    public constructor() {
        this.mySubject$.pipe(
            debounceTime(16) // delay or auditTime, debounceTime, ...
        ).subscribe(this.somethingVeryImportant.bind(this));
    }

    public codeImExecuting() {
        this.mySubject$.next('input for tasks')
    }

    private somethingVeryImportant() {
        // stuff
    }
}

class HaveSubscription1 {
    // Angular service
    constructor(private hs: HaveSubject) {
        this.hs.mySubject$.subscribe(inputStr => {
            // did I do this before somethingVeryImportant is called?
        });
    }
}

class HaveSubscription2 {
    // Angular service
    constructor(private hs: HaveSubject) {
        this.hs.mySubject$.subscribe(inputStr => {
            // did I do this before somethingVeryImportant is called?
        });
    }
}
```

If you have some versioning mechanism that will react to changes done in `HaveSubscription#` you can do this:

```js
this.mySubject$.pipe(
  map(this.calculateVersion),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
).subscribe(this.somethingVeryImportant.bind(this));
```

Comment: These are great suggestions. When I was thinking about it last night, I was naturally leaning towards your first suggestion, seems like the simplest way to tackle the problem.

Comment: It is easiest but has some disadvantages that may or may not be a problem depending on what you exactly need to do

Answer (score 0):

so this looks like you've made some suspect architecture decisions, since the flow is

1. service 1 function executes and emits from observable
2. service 2/3/etc subscribers to service 1 observable execute code that produces some output or side effect
3. service 1 function needs to execute dependent on some output or side effect from service 2/3/etc functions

this requires the subject to be aware of it's observers, which is the opposite of the rxjs philosophy. The ideal solution here would be to fix these architectural concerns. It's tough to say how to accomplish this without knowing more about how or why things occur this way or what the overall goal is.

However, you can accomplish this in a pretty reliable way, you need to add some subject on your first function that can signal completion by the dependent services:

```
class HaveSubject {
    // Angular service
    public mySubject$: Subject<string> = new Subject<string>();
    private workDone$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

    imDone() {
        this.workDone$.next();
    }

    public codeImExecuting() {
        if (this.mySubject$.observers.length) { // check for observers
            // if observers, listen for that many emissions from workDone$, only reacting to the last one
            this.workDone$.pipe(take(this.mySubject$.observers.length), last())
                          .subscribe(v => this.somethingVeryImportant());
        } else { // or just run the function, doesn't matter
            this.somethingVeryImportant();
        }
        this.mySubject$.next('input for tasks');

    }

    private somethingVeryImportant() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

and have the observers of mySubject$ call imDone() when they're done.

Comment: This is a really compelling suggestion. I was not aware that subjects could check on how many observers they had. That would be helpful at run time to check if everyone has already finished, though I agree it's not an ideal / elegant solution.